# Docker remove image rmi imageName not working

Tags: docker

I have these images
[image]

If I remove the first image it worked
[image]

But I couldn't remove the second image

[image]

Any reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to use the tag name as well. For the **new-image** it will get the **latest** tag as default

> docker rmi httpd:alpine

[image]